# Find Coordinates for point on screen?

Tags: c#, graphics, coordinates, point

The thing is I have some graphics shown in a form, rectangle for example, and I want to capture when the point gets over thees fields. So I Thoght I try to find the corrrdinates for thees rectangles, but as thay are the coords in the form it dose not match the ones with the mouse location.

So I wonder is there a way to find what coord on the screen a Point has on the screen and not in the form or controller?

Comment: I cant understand what do you want to do, can you explain more graphically ?

Comment: Posting a bit of code showing what you're currently using would help us answer your question :-)

Comment: Try and re-write the post, as Ahmed i don't quite understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each control hs PointToFoo methods for conversion. Note that you should call this from the parent of the object who's location you want:

```
Point scrPos = this.PointToScreen(panel1.Location);
```

Alternatively, you can get the panel's screen coordinates with:

```
Point scrPos = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
```

Note that the above two examples could gve different result due to the border-size of the panel.

Comment: Excellent!

now I can use

Point scrPos = menuItemForm.PointToScreen(mSize.Location);

to locate the point where the rectangle mSize is located and there by detect mouse-over for this rectangle.

Comment: might not work all the time. Check this duplicate post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768677/c-sharp-how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-a-specific-point-on-screen-not-mouseloca/20688514#20688514

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the graphics object for the form by calling `this.CreateGraphics()` within the form, then the coordinates used when you draw the rectangle should be exactly the same as those returned by the click event on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what coordinates your pointer is in? You can get the coordinates for your window with a call to `GetWindowRect()` and subtract the top/left from your mouse cursor to get client coordinates.

I seem to remember there being a function to do that for you in fact, but it's been some time since I dabbled in custom GUI controls.