# C# How to get the Coordinates of a specific Point on Screen. (not mouselocation)

Tags: c#, winforms, location, screen, coordinates

I have the following problem:
I'm writing a WinForms application with C# and i want to get the Screen - Coordinates of a part of a picture, in this case the top of this hand (marked by the red point).

Does anybody know how i can do this programmaticaly?

[image]

("Koordinaten dieses Punktes" = Coordinates of this Point)

EDIT:
sry for confusing you, the picture above should only demonstrate my problem. The actual target of my program is to move the mouse-controlled-hand of a dart game to the right position, but it isn't possible by only setting the MouseLocation to a fix Point, because every turn the dart-hand gets another x:y distance to the MouseLocation. So I need to find the Location of the dart (-arrow).

I hope that everybody knows what my problem is now.

[Picture of the dart game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAAxX.jpg)

Comment: How is code to guess that somebody drew a hand on the desktop?

Comment: What sort of information can we assume? I mean, do you know the relative coordinates of the point on the picture? Or do we have to scan through the entire desktop image pixel by pixel looking for a particular location? How is the picture drawn on the desktop? Is it part of a transparent form, or do you draw it directly onto the desktop's DC?

Comment: Its pretty close to Pattern Recogition... and red points can be even on the background image

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro, indeed sounds like a job for OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

In some event of the form use:

```
this.PointToScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(250, 300));
```

Replace the Point by the point (relative to the form) you are interested in.

Comment: It did not work for me when the window was off screen. see a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Control.PointToScreen won't work correctly if your window is minimized, hidden or off the screen.
You'll have to drop down to Interop with Win32 APIs:

so start by importing the API:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetCursorPos(out Point lpPoint);
```

and use it:

```
Point pts;
GetCursorPos(out pts);
MessageBox.Show(this, pts.ToString());
```