# Issues with Graphics.CopyFromScreen due to dpi or screen resolution changes

Tags: winforms, dpi

I am trying to take a screenshot of a contents of a Windows Forms panel when the user clicks on the print button. I am using Graphics.CopyFromScreen with the parameter sourceX and sourceY will be the location of the panel corresponding to the parent control.

The issue is that when the user changes the Dpi or screen resolution, the X and Y coordinate for the location of the panel is different. So the screenshot image is cut off. Any advise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with screen coordinates, not relative coordinates.

[Find Coordinates for point on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438283/find-coordinates-for-point-on-screen)